# Python/Openpyxl: change cell A1 in all excel worksheets within a workbook to equal the name of the worksheet tab

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

I am new to python and I bet I am coming to you guys with an extremely easy question. In the below code, I am trying to do the following steps using python and openpyxl. The first two steps work fine, but the code fails once I add in step 3. Could someone please tell me why my for loop isn't working? I know it looks very wrong now, but I have tried so many possible combinations that I am positive I am getting further from what's correct.

This code is attempting to:

1. Create a new excel workbook
2. Create new worksheets within the workbook based on a list of sheet names.
3. Set cell A1 of each worksheet equal to the worksheet name. IE: if the worksheet tab is called "Total Pivot", then I want cell A1 in that sheet to contain the text "Total Pivot". The code worked well until I added this portion. It is currently giving me an error that says-- 'WriteOnlyWorksheet' object is not subscriptable.

Thanks so much for any help. I will be very grateful for any advice. :)

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

#Create new workbook
Report1_workbook = Workbook('Report 1.xlsx')

#List of worksheets to create in Report 1
report1sheets = ["Total Summary", "Interest Summary", "Price Summary", "Total Pivot", "Total Pivot Expanded"]

#Creating worksheets with tab names in the above list.
namereport1sheets = [Report1_workbook.create_sheet(title=x) for x in report1sheets]

#Setting cell A1 in every sheet to be equal to the sheet title-- THIS IS WHAT IS CAUSING AN ERROR

for sheet in Report1_workbook.sheetnames:
    for i in range(len(report1sheets)):
        sheet["A1"].value = report1sheets[i]

Report1_workbook.save('Report 1.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your error is because you of the line `Report1_workbook = Workbook('Report 1.xlsx')`. This will open a file in Write-only mode and `cell.value` will not work. Also, if you use `.worksheet` and `.title` instead of the multiple loops, it is cleaner. The shortest/quickest way to fix it is to use `append()`. Updated code below...

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
#Create new workbook
Report1_workbook = Workbook('Report 1.xlsx')

#List of worksheets to create in Report 1
report1sheets = ["Total Summary", "Interest Summary", "Price Summary", "Total Pivot", "Total Pivot Expanded"]

#Creating worksheets with tab names in the above list.
namereport1sheets = [Report1_workbook.create_sheet(title=x) for x in report1sheets]

for sheet in Report1_workbook.worksheets: # For each worksheet.. 
    sheet.append([sheet.title])  ## Use append and use sheet.title=name of sheet

Report1_workbook.save('Report 1.xlsx')
```

For sake of completeness, if you want to use `cell`, you can use the below code. You will need to use `Report1_workbook = Workbook()` at the start and you can use `cell.value()`. But, note that this code will create a default worksheet `Sheet` which will be in addition to the sheets you create. However, you can specific which cell you want to write you data to, unlike using `append()` which will start writing from cell `A1`

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

#Create new workbook
Report1_workbook = Workbook()

#List of worksheets to create in Report 1
report1sheets = ["Total Summary", "Interest Summary", "Price Summary", "Total Pivot", "Total Pivot Expanded"]

#Creating worksheets with tab names in the above list.
namereport1sheets = [Report1_workbook.create_sheet(title=x) for x in report1sheets]

for sheet in Report1_workbook.worksheets:
    sheet.cell(row=1,column=1).value = sheet.title  ##Using sheet.cell

Report1_workbook.save('Report 1.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This solution worked for me, I was unaware that how I opened the workbook would cause these errors.